# Is it possible to host powerbi.com inside of another website?

Tags: asp.net, powerbi

I would like to embed the full power bi app inside of another website. The thinking at my office is that users will go to our one website to access various applications on our network. I know we can embed reports and dashboards, but we would like to allow users to create their own reports and dashboards from within our website by having the entire power bi app hosted inside of the web page. I've already tried adding an iframe to the specific dataset url, but that fails with error "The content cannot be displayed in a frame". Here's the iframe tag we are using

```
<iframe src="https://app.powerbi.com/groups/<group-id>/datasets/<dataset-id>" width="1000px" height= "765px" frameBorder="0" scrolling="no" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tested this for you.

Note: as my site was https, it would only load another site that was also https

```
 <embed src="https://yoursiteurl.com/" style="width:500px; height: 300px;">
```

you can edit width and height according to your needs There is no frame, but if you reduce the size and if the site is responsive you will end up with a scroll bar.

Comment: I tried it but get error "This content cannot be displayed in a frame", even though I am using the embed tag. But when I click on the link, open this content in a new window, it does open the powerbi linked in the src attribute. So the url is a working url. Is your url a path to the dataset? I know reports and dashboards work, but I need to allow users to have access to the full app so they can create their own reports or dashboards.

Comment: I got that in a http/https mismatch

Comment: Ok that does make sense. However I'm testing this locally on a dev box so I don't have an https url to test off of. Is it possible to turn on the toolbar in an embedded report and edit the report that way? I am able to show an embedded https report in my local http web app. Right now the report shows, but without the editing toolbar.

Comment: you can buy a url for $10 on Amazon Route 53, set it up as a https via aws cognito and set up an EC2 instance, running a beanstalk sample app for free, probably no bandwidth cost. You definitely need to buy a URL or have one that you can transfer in, then you will have a live test environment without any real cost.